# Change the label of the column dynamically in a DGrid

Tags: javascript, dojo

The idea is to change the label and the tooltip of the first column in the grid when the button is clicked. And when I clicked the button, the correct data is loaded, the new tooltip is set ("ChangedTooltip") but the label of the column is still the same ("principal" and not "ChangedLabel"). Do I miss something, or the approach is wrong? How can I set the new value in the label of the column?

Two .js: Principal.js and PrincipalTable.js

Principal.js

```
...
    /**
    * add events to select button
    */
    var createEventForSelectButton = function(year, period) {
        on(selectButton, "click", function(event) {
        currentQueryMap = initQueryMap(year, period);
        grid.setFirstColumn(period.value); <-- IMPORTANT!!!!!
        grid.set('query', currentQueryMap);
    });
};
...
return declare([], {
...
grid = new PrincipalTable(...);
```

PrincipalTable.js

```
var grid = declare([ SortFormatterGrid, Selection ], {
        constructor : function(args) {
        ...
        this.columns = [ {
                label : "principal",
                field : "id",
                sortFormatter : function(object) {
                    return object;
                },
                tooltip : "principal"
            }, {
          ...
        },
        setFirstColumn : function() { <-- IMPORTANT!!!!
            this.columns[0].label= "ChangedLabel";
            this.columns[0].tooltip= "ChangedTooltip";
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let dgrid rebuild the columns: this.set("columns", this.columns)